# Is it OK to have nodes with mutable attributes when using Spark's GraphX distributed functions?

Tags: apache-spark, nodes, mutable, spark-graphx

I am looking at the [implementation of a certain graph clustering algorithm](https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity) using Spark's GraphX graph analytics library. I noticed that the implementation uses a [class VertexState](https://github.com/Sotera/spark-distributed-louvain-modularity/blob/master/dga-graphx/src/main/scala/com/soteradefense/dga/graphx/louvain/VertexState.scala) with several mutable (var members).

I wonder whether doing this sort of thing could lead to incorrect behaviour, due to the fact that in distributed implementations the same node could be replicated in more than one processing node.

My question is not so much about the correctness of this practice in the context of this particular implementation, but in general.

Perhaps it is fine is one is just using certain functions such as map on the vertex set, but might be problematic if one is using others that involve more than one vertex at a time such as mapReduceTriplets?

Answer (score 1):

Having mutable members is just fine... as long as you don't mutate them. Any type of data mutation in place can result in incorrect or non-deterministic behavior. There are cases when you can use mutable accumulators with aggregations but you should never modify data stored in a distributed object.